# Python, printing range of row with delays

Tags: python, row, delay

I am new to python, I tried numerous CSV read function to print a range of rows from a one-column CSV file (no header) with some delay on each print, with no success, I want to put this into a function, but for now, I try to make the print works first, then I will try with function, Here what I have tried:

```
  from time import sleep
  from csv import reader
  import csv
  import pandas as pd

  df = pd.read_csv('test3.csv')
  print(df.iloc[25:36]) # it prints row 25 till row 36
```

I tried this with timer:

```
  df = pd.read_csv('test3.csv')
  for s in (df.iloc[25:36]):
  print(s) ; sleep(5)
```

but it only prints the first row, sleeps for 5 sec, but not printing the rest.
I am grateful for your help

Edited:

OK the new timer from Nikolaos works perfectly,
Here is a simple function that I want to make it work together with data from csv file:

```
def func1(some_id='', some_Num ='12345'):
return something.func1(some_id=some_id, some_Num = some_Num)
func1() # this works when run
```

I want to fill data in front of "some_id=" from CSV file, but not working,

```
def func1(some_id='', some_Num ='12345'):
return something.func1(some_id=some_id, some_Num = some_Num)

with open('test3.csv') as cso:
for s in islice(cso, 25, 37): # from 25 to 36 included, update as needed
    func1(s, end='')
    time.sleep(5)
```

> > Edited:
> > for learning purpose I want to learn another method of printing rows of CSV file with delay in between, so I tried the following code from Cyrex, but not working, I used visual studio code to run python, and the part of:

```
for row in list(csv_reader)
```

the error shows on closing pretense:
for row in list(csv_reader)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

the code::

```
 import json
 import random
 import time
 import os
 from time import sleep
 from csv import reader
 from itertools import islice
 import csv
 import pandas as pd

 with open('test4.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
 csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
 header = next(csv_reader)
 if header != None:  
    list = [] 
    for row in list(csv_reader)
       list.append[row]
    print(list[24:35])
    time.sleep(5)
```

here is data on the CSV file:

```
432323422016048516
3245968643672398
994751490493134145
1245290296886842
2286337388046077
5576337391667210
670175046204272300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print all the lines and then wait for 5s, try:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from csv import reader
>>> import time
>>>
>>> with open('test3.csv') as cso:
...     for s in islice(cso, 25, 37): # from 25 to 36 included, update as needed
...         print(s, end='')
...     time.sleep(5)
```

If you want to print a line, wait 5s, and continue printing and waiting, try:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from csv import reader
>>> import time
>>>
>>> with open('test3.csv') as cso:
...     for s in islice(cso, 25, 37): # from 25 to 36 included, update as needed
...         print(s, end='')
...         time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: thanks, Nikolaos for the script, It works, Perfect!, that is the way I wanted, however, I don't want to use print, instead run a function, I want to use the data from CSV to be inserted into a function. I tried it since it is outside of a function, I have a hard time to figure it out how to do it, I am grateful for any help. I will update my first post with the example function.

Comment: @Dave99 great, that it worked for you; you now have a *different* question, which is perfectly fine; I'd recommend instead of polluting *this* question to ask a *new* one and explain your *new* problem; this way what is answered here may be useful for others and it'd be easier for more folks (and me) to help you with the new problem you face

Answer (score 0):

it should be smthg like

```
from csv import reader
import time


with open('file.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)

    # Check file if empty

    if header != None:
        
        lst = [] 

        for row in csv_reader:

            
            lst.append[row]

        print(lst[24:35]) # changed 25 to 24 and 36 to 35 coz this iteration is done through lst list not through csv_reader

        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have tried a similar script that works if I print all rows from a CSV file,  but I want to print a range of rows, in my example, I had from row 25 to 36.

Comment: my bad, did not saw the range, gonna update the code in few minutes

Comment: thanks for the code, however i get error on 1st.append[row] as: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable, I don't understand the append part,

Comment: try with **for row in list(csv_reader)** actually it was successful when i tested it in vs code with python 3.9

Comment: @Dave99 i saw a typo **1st** while it's **lst**

Comment: thanks, Cyrex for the updated codes, I applied: for row in list(csv_reader), but I get "invalid syntax" on the closed pretense. I use python 3.8.3 and visual studio v.1.51,

Comment: i tested the actual posted code with csv file composed of 5 rows, and its successful. probably your csv file rows are inconsistent which means does not have same structure or maybe there is trailing **\n**, hence, plz post 10 lines of your csv to have an exact idea about its structure

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually for testing purpose I made a CSV file from notepad++ having only one column of some numbers to test, each number on a new line, no \n or comma, I am going to test again with some other CSV file. I want to test the variation of this read csv function with delay between to learn more.

Comment: I tested with other CSV file, I am still getting an error, updated my post, added the code and example of csv file.